# Saved Lists sorted by Activity doesn't display when the latest activity occurred

Tags: bug, sorting, dates, activity, saves

Lists of Saves can be sorted by: Score, Activity, Views, Newest, or Added. The *sorting* of the posts seems to work fine, but...

For example, if sorted by Activity, the list *shows* when the posts were asked or answered:

[image: List of Saves sorted by Activity - the listed items show asked and answered dates rather than modified dates]

rather than showing when the posts had their latest activity, e.g. "modified 1 month ago", (like in the Active tab of the Questions page).

---

- It makes sense to show the asked or answered dates if the list is sorted by Newest.
- But if the list is sorted by Activity, the list should show the latest activity dates.
- If sorted by Score or Views, I suppose it could go either way. But what's more important is that the scores and view counts are visible in the list (which they are).
- And if the list is sorted by Added, I suppose it'd be nice to actually see the dates that the items were saved to that list.

---

Not showing the data that the list is being sorted by, makes it harder to find the listed items that one is looking for.

Comment: There's also a bug in your red pencil.

Comment: @Shadow (I was trying to save ink)